# Convert document ready to on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to convert this document to `on()` but I don't know how. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $sub = $("#removImg").hide(),
    $chnckbox = $('input[name="chkboxplat[]"]').click(function() {
        $#sub.toggle( $chnckbox.is(":checked") );
    });
});
```

I tried `$(document).on(function(){`. Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: What you have is correct. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: cause I'm loading stuff from the dom..

Comment: But without result, the whole code stops working when I change ready to on

Comment: In this case it's not how you use `on()`. You still need the document.ready handler. If you can describe what you're actually trying to do we can show you the correct method to use

Comment: I have a video uploader.. with checkbox, when the checkbox checked the submit button will show and when it's unchecked it's hide. But when I load new video's from ajax. the hide/show submit stops working, now I found the on method. that works for new elements in dom

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of the issue in your comment you need to use a delegated event handler on the checkbox as it's dynamically appended to the DOM.

To do this you do need to use `on()`, however the syntax you had was incorrect. You need to add a new event handler, not replace the document.ready handler. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $sub = $("#removImg").hide();

    $(document).on('change', 'input[name="chkboxplat[]"]', function() {
        $sub.toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Note the use of the `change` event, not `click`, so that the code works for users who navigate via the keyboard

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just for future reference, it's always best to describe what you're attempting to do in the question rather than what doesn't work, as there may be a better way to achieve what you need

Comment: I'll appreciate your feedback for the future.

Comment: Hey me again, it seems to work but I have multiple checkboxes with the same name.. when I checked them all and uncheck one.. the button hides again? what is wrong?